# importError: No module named Coreapp (Flask and Google App Engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to run and deploy my web app on my local server. I'm learning how to use google app engine and when I command dev_appserver.py flaskapp one directory above flaskapp but inside my repo, I get this error:

```
uzuki@ubuntu:~/hw3p1s13$ ~/Downloads/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py flaskapp/
INFO     2013-03-18 03:43:12,890 appcfg.py:618] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2013-03-18 03:43:13,398 appcfg.py:636] The SDK is up to date.
WARNING  2013-03-18 03:43:13,398 dev_appserver.py:3578] The datastore file stub is    deprecated, and
will stop being the default in a future release.
Append the --use_sqlite flag to use the new SQLite stub.

 You can port your existing data using the --port_sqlite_data flag or
 purge your previous test data with --clear_datastore.

 WARNING  2013-03-18 03:43:13,400 datastore_file_stub.py:528] Could not read datastore      data from /tmp/dev_appserver.datastore
 WARNING  2013-03-18 03:43:13,618 simple_search_stub.py:975] Could not read search   indexes from /tmp/dev_appserver.searchindexes
 INFO     2013-03-18 03:43:14,431 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:656] Running application dev~robohw27 on port 8080:     http://localhost:8080
 INFO     2013-03-18 03:43:14,432 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:658] Admin console is available at:     http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
 ERROR    2013-03-18 03:44:05,236 wsgi.py:219] 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/uzuki/Downloads/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle
 handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
 File "/home/uzuki/Downloads/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 255, in _LoadHandler
handler = __import__(path[0])
ImportError: No module named coreapp
INFO     2013-03-18 03:44:05,265 dev_appserver.py:3104] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
ERROR    2013-03-18 03:44:07,858 wsgi.py:219]
```

The strange thing is I do have directory called coreapp that contains two files, `__init__.py` and views.py. The `__init__.py` folder contains

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask('coreapp')
import views
```

and my views.py file handles an HTTP request made to a particular URL. To sum it up, it does contain `from coreapp import app` . So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong ??

Just to add, in my app.yaml file inside my flaskapp directory, it contains:

```
handlers
- url: .*
script : coreapp.app
```

EDIT:

Hello everyone. I figured out my problem, it's so foolish:

I wanted "`__init__.py`" but I had "`__int__.py`". (Major typo!)

Also, I was just gedit editor in my views.py file. But I had white space and wrong apostrophes. Please let me know if anyone else is having a similar problem.

Thank you! I will answer my own question in 6 hours lol.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic 
because it is a simple typo, and this question is not helpful to future visitors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem, it's so foolish:

I wanted "`__init__`".py" but I had "`__int__.py`". (Major typo!)

Also, I was just gedit editor in my views.py file. But I had white space and wrong apostrophes. Please let me know if anyone else is having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.path.append(whereever_coreapp_is)
```

Comment: Which file would I place that in? And what's the reasoning behind it? Thanks